# Adding redirect for Django admin detail view

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to set up a redirect so that when Django CMS users are accessing a detail view for one of the admin models, they get redirected to the listing view.

I was able to successfully override the detail view within the `admin.py` file:

```
class MyAdmin(MyModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = u"admin/myadmin/change_form_content.html"
```

within the template, I'm creating a redirect back to the list view:

```
{% block content %}
    <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=/myadmin/">
{% endblock %}
```

This works fine, but it's messy. How can I move the redirect to the `admin.py` file instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly override the method responsible for displaying that view: `changeform_view`.

```
class MyAdmin(MyModelAdmin):
    def changeform_view(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return redirect('/admin/')
```

Comment: thanks! although I'm using an outdated version of Django (version 1.4), so I had to use `change_view` instead